# C# How to represent an Int as four-byte integer

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, int

I'm trying to send the `Length` of a Byte array to my server, so that it knows how much data to read.

I get the length of the `Byte[] message` array using `int messageLength = message.Length`

How do I represent this integer `messageLength` a four-byte integer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use BitConvertor  `BitConverter.GetBytes(message.Length);`

Answer (score 5):

Use the [BitConverter.GetBytes(int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
int length = message.Length;
BitConvert.GetBytes(length);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
message[0] = length & 0xFF;
message[1] = (length >> 8) & 0xFF;
message[2] = (length >> 16) & 0xFF;
message[3] = (length >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

To recover it...

```
int length = message[0] | (message[1] << 8) | (message[2] << 16) | (message[3] << 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

A byte in C# is 8 bits.. 8 bits * 4 bytes = 32 bits.. so you want to use a System.Int32.